# Hibernate not showing sql statement even with sql_show=true

Tags: hibernate, spring

I am not sure why it doesn't show sql statement. I have it working before (on older spring, I am using 3 this time)

In ApplicationContext I have :

```
<bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>my.model.*</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

In log4j:

```
# Standrd System.out appender
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# package override setting
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG, stdout
log4j.additivity.org.hibernate.SQL=false
log4j.logger.org.displaytag=INFO

log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout
```

Everything else seems fine, but it just doesn't show me the sql.

Did I miss anything?

(Or is it possible to print from SessionFactory from org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.getProperties()? It is not showing the show_sql, probably not even injected properly?)

Please help
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have added 
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
but still no luck.

Comment: By the way, I am using JPA (annotation) for mapping and I use a generic DAO to create my model's DAO (using spring to inject the model into the a class which extends HibernateDaoSupport)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

make sure DEBUG is good, at one point hibernate logging changed from DEBUG to TRACE.
Also make sure there is no threshold in your `log4j.config`.
if you want also your arguments to be displayed include `org.hibernate.type`. You may also need to set `org.hibernate.jdbc=TRACE` or try `org.hibernate=TRACE` analyse your needs and change back to proper levels per package.

Comment: The hibernate.show_sql property isn't governed by logging. It writes directly to stdout.

Comment: It did do that, but it has changed in the past. On my console I get: `[8/16/11 15:20:52:058 CEST] 00000038 SystemOut     O 15:20:52.056 DEBUG [WebContainer : 6] org.hibernate.jdbc.util.SQLStatementLogger.logStatement:111 - select obfuscate0_.OUR_ID as OUR1_77_, obfuscate0_.USR_ID as USR2_77_, obfuscate0_.OFFICE as LVE3_77_, obfuscate0_.IDG_ID as IDGT4_77_, obfuscate0_.USRID_L`

Comment: it worked. and it ended up to me my mistake, entity not loaded properly

Comment: Adding logging.level.org.hibernate=TRACE in the application.properties file worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

You have hibernate.show_sql configured correctly. Where are you looking for the output? In any case, it's better to just forget about show_sql and use Hibernate's logging instead. It's much more flexible. Remove the "hibernate.show_sql" property entirely, and in your logging config use

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
```

Note that there's no reason to mess with the additivity since everything is writing to the same appender, so this line doesn't do anything and should be removed:

```
log4j.additivity.org.hibernate.SQL=false
```

Comment: added a System.out.println on the class for debug purpose. so I think I am checking the right log. =(

Comment: it worked. and it ended up to me my mistake, entity not loaded properly

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I managed to correct this by adding a argument on JBoss launch configuration:

1. Double click on "Red Hat JBoss EAP xxx".
2. Click in "Open launch ocnfiguration" (tab "General Information").
3. Add `-Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false` on the end of "VM arguments" field.

Worked for me.